# c# oops why its not printing d in the sample code

Tags: c#, oop

Below code gives the output as "abc".

Please can someone explain why its not printing "d"

```
public class a
{
    public void m1(a obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
    }
}

public class b :a
{
    public void m1(b obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b");
    }
}

public class c: b
{
    public void m1(c obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("c");
    }
}

public class d: c
{
    public void m1(d obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("d");
    }
}

class MainRunning
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        a a1 = new a();
        b b1 = new b();
        c c1 = new c();
        d d1 = new d();

        d1.m1(a1);
        d1.m1(b1);
        d1.m1(c1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `d` to be printed?

Comment: because i m calling the method of class d

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I suspect you are trying to use method inheritance (i.e. override) but don't actually get to the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 4 methods with the same name but different argument lists. You call three of them, but not the fourth.

Comment: Exactly. To clarify, those 4 overloaded functions are all in class `d`. 3 of them are inherited, but that doesn't matter to the class.

Answer (score 6):

The method printing `d` is awaiting the instance of type `d` as its argument. No of your calls passes `d` to the method called `m1`, so other overloads are used.

You can call `d1.m1(d1)`, which will resolve in `m1(d obj)` method call, which will write `d` into your console.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't call

```
d1.m1(d1);
```

When you call `d1.m1(b1);` then only method that can be run with that param (b1) is the one contained in b class.
And for very of the three methods you run, only one class at a time can handle it and this class **is not d class** which accepts a different parameter type!!

Answer (score 1):

Please see below:

```
class MainRunning
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        a a1 = new a();
        b b1 = new b();
        c c1 = new c();
        d d1 = new d();

        d1.m1(a1);
        d1.m1(b1);
        d1.m1(c1);
        d1.m1(d1); // <== ?

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```